# Can't connect to and debug my azure app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2012, certificate, publishing

I have a mvc4 project that I have published to azure through a publish profile that I use by  right clicking my main project and go publish.
All this works great and has for a while.

But now I need to debug the app so I installet the azure tools and according to tutorials I should then have my application under "Windows Azure Compute" in server tab. I do not there is nothing under there.

If I select "Add Deployment Environment" I can click a link that says download publish settings file so I did and I got the file. When i then import it, it looks like this: http://db.tt/JkJsT3Hl

however if I now click the little arrow next to 3-Month Free Trial the arrow simply disappear. There is nothing there.

I noticed that the publich settings file I had since before was not at all the same as this new one I got now. I could not use the old one here.

I also noticed that a new Certificate showed up on the azure page like so: http://db.tt/KoqNXwUp
I should mention that before it said upload a .cer file, something i never did.

Okay thats all I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed that azure toolkit comes with a emulator (system tray)
enabled that and created a web role (right click project and chose create azure role)
and now i can debug in the emulator on my local machine and so far it has worked brilliant.

Beware that it can require you to run visual as admin to work.